# How to get notifications when execute scripts via ssh?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

**Hi everyone!**

I'm writing a shell script that contains many different sub tasks, and I will run this script on Arch Linux from Mac over ssh. I also knew some tools, Growl-notifier or terminal-notifier, can send native notifications on Mac OS.

I hope that I can receive notifications when some sub tasks are done.
Is there a way to trigger those tools except ssh back to local machine ?

It would be very appreciated if you can help me to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm using iTerm2 on my mac. My final solution is to use the iTerm2's Trigger feature, so I can assign various actions to triggers. And I'm looking forward to the iTerm2's new feature, Instant Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on Github for something called 'undistract-me'.

It allows posting alerts and messages to the Notification Center directly from the command line using a simple syntax.

I would update your shell script to include the documented syntax and send a message when each task starts or completes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your useful information. Although It is not what I really want, I still learn some great stuff from what you mentioned.